# jQuery/JavaScript - Converting CSV to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, csv

I am trying to to convert a CSV file into a javascript array.

Here is my code:

```
var segments = {
    'Segment_1':'inves_cast',
    'Segment_2':'foreged_prod',
    'Segment_3':'air_prod',
    'Segment_5':'worldwide',
    'Segment_6':'structurals'
};

var divisions = {
    'Division_1':'structurals',
    'Division_2':'airfoils',
    'Division_3':'wyman',
    'Division_4':'energy',
    'Division_5':'fasteners',
    'Division_6':'struc_comp',
    'Division_7':'mech_hard',
    'Division_8':'engine_prod',
    'Division_9':'corp',
    'Division_10':'aero',
    'Division_11':'timet',
    'Division_12':'',
    'Division_13':'spec_metals',
};

var csv = $.get('/path/to/locations.csv');

console.log(csv);

var locationArray = transformLocationData(csv);

function transformLocationData(obj) {
    var lineArray = [];
    if(obj && obj.data) {
        var text = (data.responseText);
        lines = text.split('\n');
        for(var line in lines) {
            var lineTokens = line.split(',');
            lineArray = [
                lineTokens[0],
                lineTokens[1],
                lineTokens[3],
                lineTokens[4],
                lineTokens[5],
                lineTokens[6],
                lineTokens[11],
                lineTokens[12],
                lineTokens[13],
                lineTokens[14],
                lineTokens[15],
                segments['Segment_' + lineTokens[8]],
                divisions['Division_' + lineTokens[9]]
            ];
        }
    }
    console.log(lineArray);
}
```

So what I am trying to do is us AJAX to get the csv file and then split the "responseText" *first* by line and *Second* loop through those lines and split it up by commas and then create an array based on those line numbers.

Here is a picture of the data I am getting back from the AJAX call:
[image]

With the last console log ( `console.log(lineArray);` ) it returns an empty array or really it just returns the data the is in `var lineArray = [];` which is empty if I populate it with data `var lineArray = ["Lexus", "Audi", "BMW"];` It will return that array.

Here is a plunker with all the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/CoZGfr6S9R5LDqR1drzq

I know I am doing something wrong but cant seem to get it. I'm not familiar with doing this kind of thing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays

Comment: @vlaz then why don't you give me an alternative? Instead of just telling me not to use it :) . Like I said in the original question I am new to this. And for being new (I think) I have got some good starting code. Could you please elaborate. Especially if there is a better way to do this, I'd like to know for future reference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking up information on `for...in` or even googling "for in arrays javascript" should give you enough information which I didn't feel like repeating but if you wish so: `for...in` should be used to iterate over _objects_ as it goes through all properties. With arrays it will iterate through things you probably don't intend to - in the past, one of these was the `length` property, It will also not loop in the order you necessarily want and it may skip some entries you expect. Use a normal `for` loop or ES6 `for...of`,or the functional `array.forEach` and `.map`, `.find`, `.every`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing `lineArray` with a new array every time, and you're only logging the array at the *end* of the loop. Perhaps the CSV has an empty line at the end.

If you're wanting an array of arrays, do this instead:

```
var lineArray = [];
if(obj && obj.data) {
    var text = (data.responseText);
    lines = text.split('\n');
    for(line in lines) {
        var lineTokens = line.split(',');
        lineArray.push([
            lineTokens[0],
            lineTokens[1],
            lineTokens[3],
            lineTokens[4],
            lineTokens[5],
            lineTokens[6],
            lineTokens[11],
            lineTokens[12],
            lineTokens[13],
            lineTokens[14],
            lineTokens[15],
            segments['Segment_' + lineTokens[8]],
            divisions['Division_' + lineTokens[9]]
        ]);
    }
}
console.log(lineArray);
```

**Update**:

In addition, you're not handling the results from the Ajax request properly. This line:

var csv = $.get('/path/to/locations.csv');

...does not return the CSV. Rather, it returns a Promise (sort of...). So you cannot parse `csv` like that. Rather, wait for the results. Change your code to:

```
$.get('/path/to/locations.csv').then(function (csv) {
  var locationArray = transformLocationData(csv);
}, function (err) {
  // Handle errors
});
```

As @vlaz alluded to, you'll also want to change your loop from `for..in` to a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var line = lines[i];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ya I tried that and it still gives me an empty array.

Comment: still doesn't seem to be working with these changes. The console is still showing an empty array. I have created a plunker for you too see live. https://plnkr.co/edit/CoZGfr6S9R5LDqR1drzq

Comment: You need to edit `transformLocationData` to handle the CSV, not a response object. Update is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1UnFgUoFsS7eS3DZkjMo?p=preview

Comment: aaaaahhh. Thats what I did wrong. This is working now. Thank you so much!!